# Count number of lines in a txt/log -file, swift

Tags: ios, swift

I can't figure out how to count lines in a txt/log-file.

```
var n = 0
var x = 0
while x < 1{
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test)", ofType: "log")
var text = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!

var textArr = text.componentsSeparatedByString("\r")
var rad: String = textArr[n]
n=n+1
}
```

With this code I get an "fatal error: Array index out of range" at the end of the file (but correct number of lines in variable n). I don't want the error, I want to save the number of lines in a variable. How should I do this?

Comment: The variable `n` is nowhere set in your code. – You know that array indices are *zero-based*, i.e. the last valid index is `textArr.count - 1` ?

Comment: `textArr as? Array.count`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't help you with swift but the logic would assume you proceed like this :
(which seems very close to what you did)

1. Get your file in a `string`.   You've done that.
2. Separate that `string` in an `array` (with a redundant character that would mark the end of the line in your document or an newline character (\n) )  You've done that.
3. simply `count` the items in the `array`  (You're using a string in a way that eludes me because i can't really read swift)

I'm guessing

```
var myCount = textArr.count
```

That would give you an `int` which you can do whatever you want with.

Note though that if you want to access that line in the array you'll have to use `n-1` because, as you most certainly know, if your count is 1, the item is at index `count-1` so zero. which is also maybe why you're getting an out of bounds error